# Change CSS on click and back again on next click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

I've looked around for an answer and nothing works for me. I want to be able to click a div and have the background change, then on the next click of the div I want it to change back again. The first part works, however I cannot figure out how to do the second part.

This is what works (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function() {
$('.icon').css("background-position", "0px 0px");
});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than use the .css method, I recommend using .toggleClass and put the relevant css into a class:

```
$('.icon').toggleClass('myClass');
```

your class definition:

```
.myClass { background-position: 0px 0px };
```

The .toggleClass method will add the class if it's not already present or remove it if it is.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with recomendations to use `.toggleClass()`, but if you want to use `.css()` try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.icon').each(function(){
    $(this).data('default-bg-pos', $(this).css('background-position'));
    $(this).data('state', 0);
  });
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $('.icon').each(function(){
      if ($(this).data('state')) {
        $(this).data('state', 0);
        $(this).css('background-position', $(this).data('default-bg-pos'));
      } else {
        $(this).data('state', 1);
        $(this).css("background-position", "0px 0px");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This is unnecessarely complicated

Comment: It is just illustration why it better to use .toggleClass() :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a css class and toggle it.

```
.zero{
    background-position: "0px 0px";
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.button').click(function() {

            $('.icon').toggleClass("zero")

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried toggling it but for some reason it didn't work (bad coding probably).